# How to create a plot which shows objects on y-axis and number on x-axis

Tags: r, csv, plot

I do have a lots of data which I want to plot in a special way. But I don't know how to do this on R.
The input is a csv file containing several columns. The columns I want to plot are A and D.
A contains text and D numbers. The usesd text in column A can be there several times. But the does not matter
[image]

In the end I want to get a plot which shall demonstrate the following:

[image]

I have actually no idea how to plot this:

I've tried: `plot(data1$COLUMND,data1$COLUMNA,xlab = "COLUMND", ylab = "COLUMNA");` But the result is that the text in column A is replaced by a number. So the axis get the label from 0-3 in this case.
I also tried to change the lable with the labels command. But this lead to the problem that the lables were in an aceding row. But the data in the column are not (in my example above they are, but not in my real data). Therefore R should replace 0 with the corresponding text from column A. 
For this I used the methods shown in [Quick-R guide](http://www.statmethods.net/input/valuelabels.html)
but they work not as desired and replaced the entries with null.

Answer (score 0):

you have to do two steps.

1) Make a list of vectors. Every vector is names after an unique element of column A and contains the corresponding values form column D.

2) Use the `stripchart()` function with this list.

My code approach:

```
## your data
data <- data.frame(A = c("AAA", "AAB", "AAC", "AAA", "AAE", "AAC"),
                   B = rep(12.3),
                   C = rep(20160729),
                   D = c(100,80,10,0,5,20))

## empty list to fill in the following loop
list <- list()
## get the values in column D for every unique value in column A
## an add it to the list
for (i in unique(data$A)) list[[i]] <- data$D[data$A == i]

## plot the list
stripchart(list,
           xlab = "Column D", ylab = "Column A",
           pch = 16, col = "red")
```

The result:

[Stripchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCCnU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `axis` function?

First, note that "AAD" was not in the sample data that you provided. We have to tell `R` about the values in Column A and how we want them to be ordered:

```
data1 <- data.frame(A=c('AAA', 'AAB', 'AAC', 'AAA', 'AAE', 'AAC'),
    D=c(100, 80, 10, 0, 5, 20))
data1$A <- factor(data1$A, levels=paste0('AA',LETTERS[1:5]))
```

Now we can plot.  We tell `R` to leave out the Y-axis for now (using the `yaxt` argument); we'll add them in manually later.

```
par(mar=c(6,6,4,2)) # Set margins for plot
plot(data1$D, data1$A, xlab = "Column D", ylab = "", yaxt="n", las=1)
```

Finally we add in the Y-axis labels, using the actual values instead of factor levels (i.e. the numbers).

```
axis(2, at=1:length(levels(data1$A)), labels=levels(data1$A), las=2)
mtext("Column A", side=2, line=1, las=2, at=3.2)
```

[image: Output]